# What is it called when you feel funny before visiting an old friend or relative

Tags: american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english

Imagine that you haven’t seen your relatives for ten years, and then you buy a ticket and fly over to them. You have a funny feeling: someone said it could be stress; someone else said it’s anxiety. But it shouldn’t be that since both of those are negative.

Can you have anxiety to something that you are longing to. You are not nervous either. I don’t know what it’s called. Does anyone?

Comment: butterflies - or indigestion!

Comment: Butterflies is good -- you feel butterflies in your stomach.  Also: you feel agitated, worked up, revved up, overwrought (but perhaps that one is too strong), on edge, excited.  You feel anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a *sense of anticipation*.

> **Anticipation**, or being enthusiastic, is an emotion involving pleasure, excitement, and sometimes anxiety in considering some expected or longed-for good event.
>   ...
>   Anticipation can be shown in many ways; for example, some people seem to smile uncontrollably during this period, while others seem ill or sick. It is not uncommon for the brain to be so focused on an event, that the body is affected in such a way. Stage fright is a type of anticipation, stemming from the actor or actress hoping that they perform well.
>   [- Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticipation)

Answer (score 0):

**Excitement**

From MW:

Definition of excitement for English Language Learners

```
: **a feeling of eager enthusiasm and interest** : the state of being excited

: exciting activity

: a quality that causes feelings of eager enthusiasm : an exciting quality
```